# How to tell if MediaStatus for Chromecast is loading?

Tags: android, chromecast

Currently there is no `MedaiStatus.PLAYER_STATE_LOADING` state to tell if the video is being loaded to the chromecast device.

Is there a way i can ask the GoogleCast device if I am loading data, as apposed to Buffering, Idle, Playing, or Paused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have such event exposed through the SDK. There is a couple of nice diagrams [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver) that show the flow and events that are captured (see section Media Events). If there is a any reason that you need a certain event (exposed by MediaElement) that are not exposed through the SDK, you should consider doing the following:

- Listen to that event on the MediaElement directly and inform your senders accordingly. The receiver SDK does exactly the same thing; it gets all its media events from the media element.
- Open a feature request on our [SDK tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list). There, you need to explain in detail why you need that feature and basically build a case that shows it is a valuable feature not just for your particular case, but in general.

Comment: Thanks, for clarification. This has come up do to stopping playback but leaving receiver launched when navigating away from a screen in my app. This is not a recommended experience anyways, but it is nice to know that its just not possible.